# Check if the requested user has admin privileges

Tags: c#, asp.net

In a web application, is there any way to check the requested user has got admin privileges.
Is it possible? Can you suggest one method?

For example: a front-end user requests a page in my application. I want to know whether the user that made the request has admin privileges in his client machine. I have to check whether he is logged in with an admin privileged account in the system.

I need the privileges of logged in user to the system not to my application , my application doesn't have a login. One user just request my home page or any other page and i just want to know that user is logged into his PC with an admin account or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the membership provider for you.
Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) article for more information.

**EDIT:**
After reading some given answers and other questions, read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx) article (provided by Abbas).

Especially look at the chapter *"Role Management, User Identity, and Membership".*
This explains the difference between windows authentication (login with your windows account when on an intranet) and forms authentication (login with username and password)

Comment: But my system doesn't have a login. So how can i check the role of a user?

Comment: and my application is not an intranet site.

Comment: Read the above articles, implement a membership provider (not as hard as it looks) and switch the authentication to windows authentication. This windows authentication will allow you to check if the user is an admin or not (using the membership provider, which is able to check the windows account). Furthermore I wouldn't recommend using windows authentication with an extranet website. This is not safe, and not good for the user experience. This is because the user has to sent his entire windows account over the internet so you can check if he has admin rights on his/her machine. Again not safe

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't even think that you (as a website) have the correct rights to access a windows account of a user visiting your website.

Comment: but this is what i want, i am checking its feasibility.

Answer (score 0):

you can create role and store role information in session

Comment: yes i mean you can create role like admin/user and that role should be stored in session. so that when server receive request it should know what is your privileges and render accordingly. or you want to know the active directory previlages